# Eclipse lauch fails after switching workspace

Tags: eclipse, boot, workspace

Eclipse fails to launch after I tried to switch workspace. The workspace was copied and pasted from another computer. I get this error at the log:

```
!SESSION 2014-07-09 13:32:32.143 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.4.0.I20140606-1215
java.version=1.7.0_60
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product

!ENTRY org.python.pydev.shared_core 4 4 2014-07-09 14:17:30.653
!MESSAGE java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
!STACK 0
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at org.python.pydev.runners.SimpleRunner.run(SimpleRunner.java:308)
    at org.python.pydev.runners.SimpleRunner.runAndGetOutput(SimpleRunner.java:325)
    at org.python.pydev.runners.SimplePythonRunner.runAndGetOutputWithInterpreter(SimplePythonRunner.java:95)
    at org.python.pydev.ui.interpreters.PythonInterpreterManager.doCreateInterpreterInfo(PythonInterpreterManager.java:68)
    at org.python.pydev.ui.interpreters.PythonInterpreterManager.internalCreateInterpreterInfo(PythonInterpreterManager.java:44)
    at org.python.pydev.ui.interpreters.AbstractInterpreterManager.createInterpreterInfo(AbstractInterpreterManager.java:381)
    at org.python.pydev.ui.pythonpathconf.ObtainInterpreterInfoOperation.run(ObtainInterpreterInfoOperation.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.pydev.shared_core.process.ProcessUtils.createProcess(ProcessUtils.java:100)
    at org.python.pydev.runners.SimpleRunner.createProcess(SimpleRunner.java:49)
    at org.python.pydev.runners.SimpleRunner.run(SimpleRunner.java:306)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 12 more
```

It seems to have something to do with python.. Has anyone ever stumbled upon a similar case?

Comment: Possibly missing a plugin. Copying a complete workspace from someone else is not really a great idea since this folder does not contain everything.

Comment: Does the *other* machine have Python installed while this new one does not?